# Follow Set of grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, set, grammar, set-theory

I am working on trying to compute the FOLLOW set of the following grammar:

```
E -> TX
T -> int Y | ( E )
X -> + E | ε
Y -> * T | ε
```

I have calculated the following FOLLOW set so far:

```
follow (E) = {$} U {)}
follow (Y) = follow (T)
follow (T) = follow (Y)
follow (X) = follow (E) = {$, )}
follow (E) = first ()) = {)}
```

I know that the follow (T) / follow (Y) contains {+,$,)} but I am struggling to get to that point.

Any assistance in explaining the method here would be greatly helpful.

Note: I have followed these rules

```
1)  If A is the start symbol put $ in Follow (A)
2)  If there is a production B -> αAb, then Follow (A) = First (b) 
3)  If there is a production B -> aA or B -> αAb where First (b) is ε, add Follow (A) = Follow (B)
```

Comment: Maybe your grammar is incomplete. Where does `)` come from?

Comment: You're right left it off by mistake! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out (and spent the better part of the afternoon)!

So the rules I'm following for anyone who finds this are:

```
follow(E) = follow(T)
follow(E) = first ())
follow(X) = follow(E)
follow(Y) = follow(T)
**follow(T) = first(X)** //the important one!
```

Following these rules you can build the sets:

```
follow(E) = {$, )}
follow(T) = {$, ), +}
follow(X) = {$, )}
follow(Y) = {$, ), +}
```

Which concludes the follow sets for the grammar!